# Why is logo not rendered in bootstrap navbar dropdown item - linked page?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, web-applications, template-inheritance

I am using Flask framework. I have few tabs (Home, About, Services and Contact) in my bootstrap navbar.

Services tab is a dropdown Tab which has a dropdown item called profile and it is linked to Profile.html template

All the templates (html files) inherits from base.html.

except Services >> Profile page, all the other pages are rendering logo as per the base.html.
**Logo is not getting rendered in Services >> Profile page as shown below:**
[image: Logo not rendered]

Logo getting rendered in other pages
[image: logo rendered well]

**I would like logo to be rendered in Services >> Profile page as well like all other pages (home, about and contact. Please help me resolve the issue**

**project structure:**

[image]

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="english">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/images/logo1.png">    
    <link
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={{url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/style.css')}}>    

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg-light py-lg-0 " id="customNavbar">  
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                <!-- Add logo -->
                <img src="static/images/logo1.png" alt="logo">
            </a>
            
            <button class="navbar-toggle-collapsed d-block d-sm-block d-md-none" type="button"
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" 
                    aria-expanded="true" 
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    id="togglerButton">
                    
                    <span class="line"></span> 
                    <span class="line"></span> 
                    <span class="line" style="margin-bottom: 0;"></span>
            </button>
    
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/"><strong>Home</strong></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/About"><strong>About</strong></a>                        
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <strong>Services</strong>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/Services/Profile">Create profile</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Service 2</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/Contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>        

            <form class="lg-flex">
                <button type="button" href="/signin"  class="btn btn-custom">Sign In</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
        </nav>    
    </div>

    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    {% block content%}
    {% endblock%}
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Profile.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block title %}Profile{% endblock %}

{% block content%}
    <h1> Profile Page! </h1>
{% endblock%}
```

**routes.py**

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint
routes = Blueprint('routes', __name__)

@routes.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('Home.html')

@routes.route('/About')
def about():
    return render_template('About.html')

@routes.route('/Services/Profile')
def profile():
    return render_template('Profile.html')

@routes.route('/Contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('Contact.html')
```

****init**.py (double underscores before and after init not visible here)**

```
from flask import Flask
from .routes import routes

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(routes, url_prefix='/')      
    return app
```

**main.py**

```
from Website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a direct link to the image source, so the Profile page is trying to find logo1.png in `/Services/static/images/` rather than just `static/images/` because of the routing as `/Services/Profile`.

You can use **`url_for`** to get the logo image, regardless of the page's location relative to the static folder, like you did with the stylesheet. It would look like this:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/images/logo1.png') }}" alt="logo">
```